# Custom Module : "Product is not compatible with Page Builder" get error when upload to marketplace

Tags: magento2, custom, marketplace, page-builder

I'm submitting my custom Maintenance Mode module in the marketplace but they are giving me error as below,

```
Product is not compatible with Page Builder - Version 2.0.0 claims to be compatible with Page Builder, but the zip file does not support this claim
```

This is the only message I got from the marketplace. Also, there is nothing related to page builder in my module

Let me know if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have selected Page Builder Compatibility on Technical submission.
Is your module related to Page builder and is it compatible with it? if not then unselect Page Builder Compatibility and check with submitting your module on the marketplace. Check the screenshot[image]